# Import multiple text files onto Matlab to analyze the data

Tags: matlab

I am really new in matlab. So i am trying to learn the very basics. I have 8 tsv files with names like 2004.07.01.0000.tsv, 2004.07.01.0300.tsv, where each file has 72 rows and 144 columns. I am trying to automatically import all of those files to matlab in a matrix form to calculate the mean, median, skewness (for data correction). What I did is that I imported one file (2004.07.01.0000.tsv) using matlab gui, then I generated a function called importfile. I am trying to use a for loop to access all the data in those files but I could not figure it out. I tried (not sure at all):

```
for fileNum=1:8;
startRow=1;
endRow=72;
filename
a=importfile(filename, startRow, endRow);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `importfile()` function works correctly, in this manner at every for-loop iteration you'll overwrite `a` with the most recent imported file. You should concatenate all your files (i.e. matrices) instead.

A matrix concatenation can either be done by rows (i.e. horizontal concatenation) or by columns (i.e. vertical concatenation). As I understand, you want a vertical concatenation in order to generate a unique matrix with 144 columns and as many rows as your single files contain.

Thus you should change the loop as follows

```
myMatrix=[];
for fileNum=1:8;
    startRow=1;
    endRow=72;
    filename
    myMatrix=[myMatrix ; importfile(filename, startRow, endRow)];
end
```

The vertical concatenation can be done by means of the `;` operator, thus an instruction like `A=[B ; C]` will create a matrix `A` by concatenating matrices `B` and `C`. In your case you initialize `myMatrix` as empty and then you will vertically concatenate (in an iterative fashion) all outputs from `importfile()`, that are your `.tsv` files.

At the end of the loop, `myMatrix` should have size `NxM` where `M` is 144 and `N` is the sum of the number of rows across all your files (8*72).

**Update**
If you have to pass explicitly the filename to the `importfile()` function you can create a cell array of strings in which each element of the cell is a filename. Thus in our case the cell array will be something like:

```
filenames={'filename1.tsv','filename2.tsv',...,'filename8.tsv'};
```

obviously you must replace the strings inside the cell with the proper filenames and finally you can slightly edit the loop as follows

```
myMatrix=[];
for fileNum=1:8;
    startRow=1;
    endRow=72;
    myMatrix=[myMatrix ; importfile(filenames{i}, startRow, endRow)];
end
```

In this manner, at every loop iteration the i-th filename will be given as input to `importfile()` and hopefully it'll be loaded.

For this to work you should (let's make things simple)

1. place your Matlab script and obviously the function `importfile()` in the same folder containing your .tsv files
2. set said folder as the Current Folder

or if you have the .tsv files in a given folder and your scripts in another folder, then the Current Folder must certainly will be the folder containing your scripts and the filenames inside the cell array `filenames` must contain the entire path, not just the proper filenames.

Comment: Thank you Alessiox. I still could not figure it out, because in my importfile function that was generated using matlab GUI it used the word filename to refer to one of my files which was 2004.07.01.0000.tsv, but how can I get your loop to use all my 8 files as mentioned in my original question. Again I am new, so bear my ignorance please.

Comment: @RachidBrah answer updated

Comment: Where should I integrate  filenames= {'filename1.tsv','filename2.tsv',...,'filename8.tsv'};
 
I put it in my importfile function and it returned an error message.
Alessiox, forget that I told you I generated a function using matlab GUI.if you have a little time, could you read my original post and approach my problem step by step please? I am sure my issue is that I am not connecting my script to my function as well as probably the content of the function itself. I appreciate it really!  by the way the function, script are in current folder

Comment: Alessiox. I combined yours with someone else's advice and it worked for me. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Now I have a one matrix that contains all my data. How can I calculate the mean, std deviation of all the elements in the matrix plz

Comment: @RachidBrah Matlab has several built-in commands such as `mean()` and `std()` which evaluate the mean and standard deviation, respectively. From your post it's not clear whether you want to evaluate mean by rows, columns or with respect to the whole matrix and my suggestion is to read the Matlab documentation in order to look for the proper syntax for your case