# Import multiple text files onto Matlab

Tags: matlab

I already asked this question before but in a wrong way. So I am going to reformulate it.
I have 8 tsv files with names like 2004.07.01.0000.tsv, 2004.07.01.0300.tsv, where each file has 72 rows and 144 columns (so I have 10368 elements in each matrix or file). I am trying to automatically import all of those files to matlab and generate vectors (so I assume I will have 72x144=10368 vectors) that I am gonna use for an analysis. For example vect1 will have 1st element from file1, 1st element from file2,…,1st element from file8. Vect2 will have 2nd element from file1, 2nd element from file2,…,2nd  element from file8 and so on. I am trying to use a double loop and the concatenate command, but I am not getting anywhere. Simply I am stuck. I would appreciate any help please! Thank you

Comment: Do the TSV files only contain numbers?

Comment: Concatenate your matrices along the third dimension as you import them. Using a [multidimensional array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html) is a much smarter design choice than trying to make that many individual vectors. You also need to provide a [mcve] and explain why your basically [identically worded previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421257/import-multiple-text-files-onto-matlab-to-analyze-the-data) isn't sufficient.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed for your reply. yes tsv files only contain numbers.

Comment: My code was:    myData=[];
numFiles = 8;
startRow = 1;
endRow = 72;
names = dir('200*.tsv');
names = {names.name};

for counter = 1:numFiles
     myData=[myData ; importfile1(names{counter}, startRow, endRow)];
end
A=myData(:);
mean = mean(A)
STD= std(A)
skewness=skewness(A)
hist(A,50);

Comment: This code was giving me the mean, STD... for all my data, but actually what I needed was the mean for every vector that is made up of 1st element from file1, 1st element from file2,…,1st element from file8. Vect2 will have 2nd element from file1, 2nd element from file2,…,2nd element from file8 and so on

Comment: I created tsvDirectory with all my files in it  and I made it current. When I run your script exactly as it is

Comment: the result is in the workspace is :allArrays [],dirOutput 0x1 struct,i [],tsvDirectory './tsv'. it looks like an empty matrix. is there a way to attach an image in here?

Comment: 'numFiles = 8;'
    endRow = 72;
    endCol = 144;
    myData = zeros(endRow,endCol,numFiles);

    names = dir('200*.tsv');
    names = {names.name};

    for counter = 1:numFiles
        myData(:,:,counter) = dlmread(names{counter},'');
    end

    for i=1:72
            for j=1:144
                [i j]=myData(i,j,:)
            end
    end

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have all eight TSV files in a single directory (without any other TSV files there), specified with `tsvDirectory` below.

```
clearvars

%% Parameters
% Where your TSV files live, relative to your current path.
tsvDirectory = './tsv';

%% Run
% `dir` returns a list of files with metadata.
dirOutput = dir([tsvDirectory filesep() '*.tsv']);

% This will hold the data from all files. It's a 72 by 144 by `N` array, where
% `N` is the number of TSV files.
% N.B. If your TSV files don't have exactly this size, you may run into some
% (easily-fixable) errors.
allArrays = zeros(72, 144, numel(dirOutput));

for i = 1 : numel(dirOutput)
  filename = [tsvDirectory filesep() dirOutput(i).name];
  oneArray = dlmread(filename, '\t');
  allArrays(:, :, i) = oneArray;
end
```

This loops over each file and slurps them in via [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html). It builds a 72 by 144 by 8 (or however many TSV files you have) 3D array.

So `allArrays(1,1,8)` gives you the top-left entry in the eighth file.

`allArrays(72, 144, 1)` gives you the bottom-right entry in the first file.

`allArrays(1,1,:)` gives you the top-left entry in all eight files.

`allArrays(:,:,5)` gives you the 72 by 144 array in the fifth file.

Post a comment if you have trouble extracting the appropriate means/variances/histograms.